# MySQL primary key cleanup

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have a fairly large database that I use for tracking items installed in a home by our service reps. For programmatic simplicity I wrote the tracking page so that every time anyone updates, removes or adds a new installed item it totally clears that home's installed item list and rebuilds it from scratch.

This works very well and has been error free in actual use, but now I've come into a different problem that I'm a bit worried about. The primary key that is used to track each particular item in the home has grown exponentially, because for every update it clears out old numbers and starts again from the highest auto_increment. This means I have large gaps in my ids and my highest index is thousands of numbers higher than the actual count of installed measures.

For clarification: I don't care that there are gaps in the ids, I built my system to only use that number as a foreign key reference to the billing information for it and it's never displayed. My actual concern is that I'm going to run out of digits far, far sooner than should be possible.

I know that I could change my script around to be "more efficient" and not delete items that  don't change and I may end up doing that in the future (this issue is a symptom of the purpose of my tracking radically changing in the middle of a project. Thanks, boss), but in the mean time I'd like to know if there is a way to "clean up" my ids. Everything that depends on those numbers is set to cascade so there shouldn't be an issue with updating the keys. Basically I'd like to start with 1, eliminate the gaps between the ids and avoid clashing with existing ids as the script runs.

I'm hoping that someone can provide a simple means of doing this, hopefully one that can be implemented as a stored procedure and run routinely.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to reset the auto_increment:

1. Truncate the table
2. Reset the auto_increment

This is done by:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=10000
```

So, you can just clear the auto_increment.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to increase the integer size. Use BIGINT, not INT.

Comment: As I understand it, altering the `AUTO_INCREMENT` only changes the value of the next row inserted into the table to be whatever you set `AUTO_INCREMENT` to, right? It doesn't have any bearing on previously entered rows? What I want to do is clean up the primary key values of already entered rows.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand you then... There are two possibilities: Write a script, which detects empty pk's or as i wrote: use BIGINT. I think the BIGINT would be a good solution. I don't think you would get   to the limit of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 pk's ;-)

Comment: Surprisingly, at the rate I'm burning through digits I probably would. I really just need to update the page to not be so wasteful, but it simply wasn't an issue in the first set of critera they gave me. So the next step is to get it to run as a stored procedure instead of an external script, but I'm not yet sure of how to go about it. Need to get a book.